# How do you keep a Table Visible in ASP.NET while browsing a Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I'm encountering a problem when working on our ASP.NET website:

I had a table hidden until a specified button was clicked. Once that button was clicked, the table - along with it's content - will be visible by that point-on. One of the contents of that table is a Calendar. The problem is this - whenever I switch the year in the Calendar, the table goes back to its hidden state.

I recognized this because I placed the `table_Name.visible = false;` property at `Page_load`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   my_Table_name.Visible = false;
}
```

I tried fixing it, so my first solution was this:

```
int counter = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        additional_Tabe.Visible = false;
        counter += 1;
    }
}
```

My solution didn't work.

- My second solution is Regular Expression
- My third solution is using Drop Down Lists to individually represent Month / Day / Year

The problem with my second and third solution is that I'll have to replace all Calendar my group-mates have placed with either of my solutions which is pretty much a tedious, but doable task.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to prevent the table from going back to it's hidden state while the user switches the year of the Calendar, select a date, or generally plays around with the Calendar.

Comment: Hey, it worked! Thanks for that

Comment: Thank you for approving my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `Page.IsPostBack` property inside of `Page_Load`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.ispostback?view=netframework-4.8 `it returns true if: the page is being loaded in response to a client postback; otherwise, false.` You can wrap your `my_Table_name.Visible = false;` in this conditional and only set it to false if it is a postback

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
       my_Table_name.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int counter = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(!PostBack)
      {

              if (counter == 0)
              {
                   additional_Tabe.Visible = false;
                   counter += 1;

              }
       }

}
```

Used this Code...